# Address of a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Why can't we store the address of a pointer in another pointer? Pointer is just a special type of a variable and it has some address, but why can't I store that address into another pointer?

```
int main()
{
    int * ptr;
    int * q;
    q = &ptr;
}
```

Why is this code wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can store the address of a pointer - or any other object type - in another pointer. But you have to get the type right; you're trying to store the address of a pointer in a pointer to `int`, not a pointer to a pointer.

```
int ** q = &ptr;   // pointer to pointer to int
```

Comment: why to use **, any logical reason??

Comment: @NileshKumar: It means "pointer to pointer". In general `<type>*` means "pointer to `<type>`"; so `int*` means "pointer to `int`" and `int**` means "pointer to pointer to `int`".

Comment: In addition, the type of the "address-of" operator `&` is _pointer-to-operand-type_. So if you have an `int foo` and do `&foo`, the result type is `int *`. Likewise, if you have a `char * bar` and do `&bar`, the result type is `char **`. So `&` adds another star ;-)